# Using category and its sub-categories products attributes as filter in products pages

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, ajax

I have some categories and subcategories for each of them. And finally, some products under these subcategories.

What I want is to choose some attributes of these categories and subcategories products to show in products page as a search filter.

For example, I have these:

Categories:

```
computers:
  laptops
    weight
    color
  pc
    motherboard
    casing-box
```

So, for example, I want the `color`, `weight`, and `motherboard` as filters.
In this case, if a user selects `Computers` category, he can see the motherboard, color, and weight as filters available in the sidebar, but if he selects `laptops`, he can only see the `weight` and the `color` as filter in the sidebar.

How can I do this in WordPress?

Is it possible to do this in `Advanced AJAX Product Filters plugin`?
If not is there any way to do this with any plugin or any code snippets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do it with [Advanced AJAX Product Filters](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-ajax-filters/) plugin. It allows you to use attributes in the filter. Follow these steps:

1. Install and activate the plugin.
2. In the right sidebar, click on **Widgets**.
3. Under **Filter By** option, select **Attribute**. Under **Atrribute**
   option, which is located beside **Filter By**, choose the attribute
   of your desired category / subcategory.
4. Finally, click on the **Save** button.

Comment: thanks, that was the trick but the new version is a little bit different though.

Answer (score 0):

I want to do something similar in multi-vendor marketplace BUT use it on each vendor's shop, on only THEIR products, to by filtered by product category only. I thought it would be nice if a filter would limit the results for only the shop being viewed. I've tried multiple plug-ins and they filter on ALL vendors so I'm stuck as I don't know enough about modifying code to get what I need.

I realize this type of reply isn't encouraged, but it is one of the very few that I've seen that addressed what I'm attempting, so please excuse my piggy-backing, thanks! :)